# calling ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript from ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have a problem with calling a javascript Function from ASP.net;
all the samples I have seen are in Button click Event,
but I want to check something in Page_load and if the result was FALSE, show the user an alert and Redirect to another page. I tried these codes , but none of them runed, and the page redirected without any alert

1.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey", 
    "alert('my message');", true);
}
```

2. 

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Alert","alert('my message');", true);
                    Response.Redirect("~/register.aspx", false);
                    return;
  }
```

I also tried `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, but it had not worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check something on page load with javascript then use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Your code here
} );
```

or in javascript

```
window.onload
```

Comment: I should check a session in Page_Load , and if it was null, after alert redirect to another page. how should I do it in javascript? could I redirect to another page in a script?

Comment: I checked ($(document).ready(function () ): but it doesnt work. because as I know, It runs after completing the page load process, and I should show the "alert" to user before that.

Comment: You can check the session in javascript as well..
Use var mysession = <%= Session["SessionName"] %>

and t redierct your page you can use window.location in javascript

Comment: thanks, but one question: if I dont want the other serverside codes for page_load to be executed , what should I do? I mean, if I check the session in JavaScript in $(document).ready, then it will be run after all codes in "page_load", and I dont want them to be run if the session return "False".its an Overhead for the system.

Comment: You can do a workaround like check the session in your serverside page_load(as this will run before $(document).ready) and then save your result in a hidden field on the page and in $(document).ready function you can check the value in the hidden field and do your stuff depending on the value..

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet will not work because you are redirecting the response before the page gets sent to the browser. Your first code snippet should work, however, you need to add the redirection logic right after the call to `alert` using client-side script. You can set the `window.location` property with the url you want to redirect the user to

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey", 
    "alert('my message');window.location='YOUR_URL_HERE';", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have tried `RegisterClientScriptBlock` with no joy. I use it in a page load event to set a bunch of user permissions on my page with no issue. Do you have a script manager present in your front end?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

It should be place directly after your opening `<form>` tag, then server side in your page load call it like this...

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "callJs", "yourJsfunction();", true);
```